# Which AWS service supports analytics for DynamoDB statistics?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, analytics, average

I'm looking for an AWS service that allows me to make simple calculations such as the moving average of an attribute in my DynamoDB table.

I tried EMR but it is much too expensive for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First enable the Stream on your DynamoDB table. Next use Kinesis Firehose to batch up to 15 minutes worth of update into files in S3. Enable event triggers on the S3 bucket and create a lambda function that computes the moving average for various starting times and intervals given the Firehose data. Finally, publish those statistics to Cloudwatch Metrics.